# SurfaceView непредсказуемо обрезает контент

Tags: android, android-layout, customview, android-mediaplayer

Разрабатываю видео приложение для ТВ приставок. Проблема в том, что для SurfaceView (показывает видео из MediaPlayer) при режиме показа "растянуть по вертикали" высчитываются координаты (одинаковые для обеих приставок), например, **left: -960, top: 0, right: 960, bottom: 1080**, далее передаваемые в метод **mySurfaceView.layout(left, top, right, bottom)**. На двух разных приставках (обе android 7 и одно разрешение 1920x1080) разное поведение: первая обрезает невошедшую картинку (на рамку снизу и сверху не обращайте внимания) (мне нужно это поведение)
[image: обрезанная]
, а вторая сжимает изображение.

[image: сжатая]

SurfaceView(wrap_content) добавлено с помощью addView() в кастомный RelativeLayout(match_parent height и width), лежащий внутри FrameLayout.

**Пробовал, но не помогло:**

- clipChildren = false для всех родительских view сразу. - нет реакции.
- mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(...with_cropping) - сжало картинку по диагонали, чтобы вписалось в пол экрана.
- сравнил атрибуты всех 3ех view (SurfaceView, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout) между 2 приставками (в Layout inspector) - абсолютно идентичны
- sv.setClipBounds(...) - пытаюсь для сжимающей приставки обрезать сам, пока безуспешно.